# Div bind click using Jquery doesn't react on keypress

Tags: jquery, html, click, accessibility, keypress

I'm using jQuery bind for click event on div elements. I want to make it accessible, so I assigned tabindex for div. Which is probably not XHTML valid, but at least tab is stopping where I want. The problem is, that pressing ender key is not triggering event in Firefox (5). In opera it works. Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NSpb3/13/

Input works for both click and enter key.

Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, should work according to specs. `This means that an element that is only focusable because of its tabindex attribute will fire a click event in response to a non-mouse activation (e.g. hitting the "enter" key while the element is focused).` http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html

Answer (score 0):

hey try this http://greatwebguy.com/programming/dom/default-html-button-submit-on-enter-with-jquery/

And code: http://jsfiddle.net/NSpb3/17/

Comment: Tabbed submit (space or enter) of div doesn't work here in Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding 'click', which is NOT a key press? If you wan't to register the enter-key for you div, you should bind the `keyup` event and check if the user has pressed enter.

Comment: I was relying on accessible implementation of jQuery - works for example in Opera...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your code that binds a key press event to the div. This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/NSpb3/16/

Comment: The problem of this is, that it fires the event twice when enter is hitted for example in Opera as jQuery is "trying" to be accessible and binds also keyboard events when binding click.